IPC between non-isolated and isolated CPUs
I have 2 CPUs - cpu1 and cpu2. Process A (non-real-time) runs on cpu1, Process B (real-time) runs on cpu2. I want to isolate cpu2 from the Linux scheduler by using isolcpus or tuned-profiles-realtime. Can I still use IPC (Unix socket, dbus, shmem) to communicate between Process A and Process B? What about user space IPC like dbus?

As I know, unix sockets is to communicate using file-like interfaces. They can be either local (within the same system) or remote (across a network). So isolation on cpu2 won't affect their functionality.
Dbus is user space mechanism and won't affect by scheduler.
But I'm not sure about shmem, but I think it is ok.

Thanks, that's what I figured. The only thing that's giving me pause is "Isolating CPUs generally involves: removing all user-space threads;".
Source: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_for_real_time/7/html/tuning_guide/isolating_cpus_using_tuned-profiles-realtime

I didn't dive in RT world and I don't think I can help further. But in this link, they said: Sharing data between applications: Use mmap to pass data around.
